# Downcast detecting tool for C#

Tags: c#, downcast

Working with legacy moderate size project. I have implemented one feature using Decorator pattern, and it works great except that it breaks crappy code that uses downcast from interface to implementation.
The question is: is there any tool or compiler flag or something, that can help me find all cases of using downcast. It is ok for me to find all cases for all types.

I have some code to elaborate my problem:

there were

```
interface IComponent {}
class Concrete : IComponent {}
...
IComponent obj = new Concrete()
```

and now

```
interface IComponent {}
class Concrete : IComponent {}
class Decorator : IComponent
{
   private IComponent _imp = new Concrete()
}
...
IComponent obj = new Decorator()
```

and bad code breaks on casting obj to Concrete, like (Concrete) obj.

Comment: How does `(Concrete)obj` break your code?  `obj` is a `Concrete` so the cast should work at run time.  Did you mean that you are casting to `Concrete` when it's actually a `Decorator`?  Either  way down casting is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: If `Concrete` isn't sealed why not just use it as your base instead of `IComponent`

Comment: If you want `Decorator` to be used 100% differently than `Concrete` when used as IComponent then just explicitly implement `IComponent`

Comment: @juharr Sorry, my original code snipped was not correct. I have fixed it. I think the problem is obvious now

Answer (score 5):

Temporarily mark `Concrete` with `ObsoleteAttribute`.  Then check the Errors List in Visual Studio for warnings about using obsolete code.  Double clicking these will take you to the code that is using `Concrete`.

Comment: Yes, it's good option. But i actually have a lot of such changes, with different type. So I would like to get rid all of downcasts.

Comment: Are you using visual studio 2015?

Comment: Actually VS2013. But I can upgrade temporary just for fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a custom Code Analyzer if you are using Visual Studio 2015.  This would give you incredible control over code validation rules.  It's a bit on the complex side though.  Details can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt573715.aspx